# Example Flex Box layout for Android 6 (stock browser - WebView)

Tags: android, android-webview, flexbox, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need a way to make Flex Box work in Android  WebView stock browser, I was able to achieve proper layouts on older Android devices running Android 4.4, but when I use it on Android 6, the page renders blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Flex Layout</title>

<style>
    html,
    body,
    .container {
        height: 100vh; /*setting 100% here doesn't help either, and makes Android 4.4 render a blank page*/
        margin: 0px;
    }


    .container {
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

        .container > * {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .container > .header,
        .container > .footer {
            height: 50px;
            background: grey;
            color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .container > .main {
            -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: blue;
        }
</style>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
            <div class="main">
                Some content
            </div>
            <div class="footer">Footer  </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works just fine on Android 4.4 WebView, but completely fails on Android 6 WebView, it works on Android 6 Chrome browser without any issues though.

Is there any way to make this work on Android 6 WebView?

Comment: Hard to tell based on the info provided. Have you run your CSS through [**autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)?

Comment: Yeah, autoprefixer doesn't help, I would be grateful for any super simple FlexBox page that works on Android 6 WebView - nothing I've found works so far...